# Programmatic generation of Literal options

Tags: python, mypy

MyPy's Literal type can be super useful for defining available options. Is it possible to generate a literal type programmatically, e.g. from a canonical registry?

e.g.

```py
class Dispatcher():
    func_reg = {
        'f1': my_func,
        'f2': new_func,
        'f3': shoe_func,
    }

    def dispatch(cls, func_name: Literal[*func_reg.keys()]) -> Whatever:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

According to the [`mypy` documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#parameterizing-literals):

> Literal types may contain one or more literal bools, ints, strs, bytes, and enum values. However, literal types **cannot** contain arbitrary expressions: types like `Literal[my_string.trim()]`, `Literal[x > 3]`, or `Literal[3j + 4]` are all illegal.

Comment: The key here seems to be that Literal types let you indicate that an expression is equal to **some specific primitive value**. As such, Literal accepts `enum` *values*, but not enums themselves.

Comment: MyPy likes this: `Literal[my_enum.A, my_enum.B]`, but not `Literal[my_enum]`

Comment: Couldn't you just use `my_enum` in the latter case?

Answer (score 0):

As @BrokenBenchmark notes, it is not possible to auto-generate `Literal` types. However, if the end goal is just to require specific values generated from some kind of function registry, we can hack it with `enum.Enum`.

To quote [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#interactions-with-enums-and-exhaustiveness-checks)

> rather than entirely special-casing enums, we can instead treat them
> as being approximately equivalent to the union of their values...
> the Status enum could be treated as being approximately equivalent to Literal[Status.SUCCESS, Status.INVALID_DATA, Status.FATAL_ERROR]

Here, functions are "registered" by adding an enum value that is an exact uppercasing of the function name to the FuncNames enum. This is not a pretty or robust solution, but it runs, it supports single-location registration of a function for type-checked dispatch, and mypy handles the required enum values as expected.

```
from enum import Enum, auto

def f():
    return "f"

def g():
    return "g"

def h():
    return "h"

class Dispatcher():
    # Build the enum used to register the functions
    class FuncNames(Enum):
        """
        The enum names here _must_ be exact uppercase-ings of the function
        names. The names will be lowercased and evaluated to register their
        associated functions
        """
        F = auto()
        G = auto()
        H = auto()


    # NOTE: The functional syntax works just as well
    # FuncNames = Enum('FuncNames', 'F G H')


    # Comprehensions can't access names defined in the class block,
    # so use a standard for loop
    func_reg = dict()
    for name in list(FuncNames):
        func_reg[eval(f"FuncNames.{name.name}")] = eval(str(name.name).lower())


    @classmethod
    def dispatch(cls, func_name: FuncNames):
        """
        Prints the return from a registered function.
        Can only be called with an item from FuncNames
        """
        print(cls.func_reg[func_name]())

Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.FuncNames.F)
Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.FuncNames.G)
Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.FuncNames.H)
# Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.FuncNames.I) -> "FuncNames has no attribute I"
# Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher2.FuncNames) -> "incompatible type"
# Dispatcher.dispatch('MyPy hates me!') -> "incompatible type"
```

Interestingly, though it feels cleaner to generate the enum itself from a list of the functions themselves, MyPy chokes on this.

```
class Dispatcher2():
    # Build an enum used to register these (the actual functions)
    funcs_to_register = [f, g, h]
    enum_names = [func.__name__.upper() for func in funcs_to_register]
    joined = ' '.join(enum_names)
    FuncNames = Enum('FuncNames', joined)

    func_reg = dict()
    for name in enum_names:
        func_reg[eval(f"FuncNames.{name}")] = eval(name.lower())


    @classmethod
    def dispatch(cls, func_name: FuncNames):
        """
        Prints the return from a registered function.
        Can only be called with an item from FuncNames
        """
        print(cls.func_reg[func_name]())

Dispatcher2.dispatch(Dispatcher2.FuncNames.F)
Dispatcher2.dispatch(Dispatcher2.FuncNames.G)
Dispatcher2.dispatch(Dispatcher2.FuncNames.H)
```

The above runs as expected, but mypy presumably can't infer the values present in the enum unless it is statically defined, so it errors.

```
> mypy enums_typing.py 
enums_typing.py:19: error: Enum() expects a string, tuple, list or dict literal as the second argument
enums_typing.py:36: error: "Type[FuncNames]" has no attribute "F"
enums_typing.py:37: error: "Type[FuncNames]" has no attribute "G"
enums_typing.py:38: error: "Type[FuncNames]" has no attribute "H"
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

TLDR:
In order to define a fixed set of choices that MyPy can check against, you must define them statically. It may then be possible to use those statically-defined choices to programmatically build your function registry.